# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

srno is being successfully fetched from a textbox

```
<?php
    $srno = $_POST['srno'];
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("visit");
    $sql ="UPDATE visitor SET Exit='".$ab."' WHERE srno=$srno"; 
    mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());
    ?>
```

Comment: you have no value for $ab is well. Which you are using in your query. $srno, is that string or number/integer??

Comment: $ab is a date which i am able to fetch successfully and $srno is a integer

Answer (score 4):

1. If `$srno` is a string you're missing quotes around it
2. `$ab` is not defined
3. [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).
4. **You are also wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)**

Answer (score 1):

To further elaborate on [**John (Conde's) answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26208871/), `exit` is a MySQL reserved word:

- **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html**

Either rename it to something else, or wrap it in backticks:

```
$sql ="UPDATE visitor SET `Exit`='".$ab."' WHERE srno=$srno";
                          ^    ^ backticks
```

or (if `$srno` is a string, as John stated in his answer)

```
$sql ="UPDATE visitor SET `Exit`='".$ab."' WHERE srno='$srno'";
```

You have used `mysql_error()` on `mysql_query()` which should have signaled the syntax error, something you have not shared completely in your question, only as the question's title which does not show us the complete error message, however I am certain it is something to the effect of
`...MySQL server version for the right syntax near 'Exit...`

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help during production testing.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

which will signal an `Undefined variable...` warning for `$ab`.

Comment: Thanks Fred it was with the help of backticks that the query was able to be executed

Comment: @GauravGupta if it work you should accept his answer. And dont forget to check the link. which he gave in his answer